# What is the Delphi declaration for char***

Tags: delphi

I have a C based DLL that exports a function that has char*** as an argument, this is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer of char (Non-unicode) My question is, after much frustration, what is the equivalent declaration at the Delphi end?

I've tried for example:

```
 // C Method declaration
 void method (char*** arg)


 TArrayOfPAnsiChar = array of PAnsiChar;
 PArrayOfPAnsiChar = ^TArrayOfPAnsiChar;
 PPArrayOfPAnsiChar = ^PArrayOfPAnsiChar;

 // Delphi declaration
 procedure method (var p : PPArrayOfPAnsiChar); cdecl;

 p : PPArrayOfAnsiChar;
 method (p)
```

But I'm not getting anything sensible back. Any suggestions? The var in the declaration is of course already a pointer so perhaps that's where I am going wrong. I've tried many variants, written down on paper what the structure is and reverse engineered a Delphi declration but to no avail. This DLL is used in other C based applications so I assume its functioning correctly.

Using XE6

Comment: It depends on what `char***` represents. It could be different things. You have to read the docs to know.

Comment: True, I should have been more explicit, in this case char*** is a pointer to a pointer that points to an array where each element points to a string. However the answer given was enough to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case char*** is a pointer to a pointer that points to an array where each element points to a string.

This implies that the callee is returning data to the caller. So you want to use:

```
procedure method(out Arg: PPAnsiChar); cdecl; external dllname;
```

where `PPAnsiChar` is `^PAnsiChar`. Note that `PPAnsiChar` is defined in the `System` unit.

The C code has three levels of indirection. The outermost is how function passses data from callee to caller. That's represented as a Delphi `out` parameter. The remaining two levels of indirection are captured in `PPAnsiChar`. Finally C's `char` is an 8 bit type on Windows and so maps to `AnsiChar`.

You will also need to iterate over the array when the function returns. Like this:

```
var
  StrArr: PPAnsiChar;
  Str: string;
....
method(StrArr);
while StrArr^ <> nil do
begin
  Str := StrArr^;
  Inc(StrArr);
end;
```

I'm assuming that the length of the array is indicated by a terminating null pointer. If instead you are told the length, you use a for loop as should be obvious.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use `array of`, because that declares a dynamic array, and use `AnsiChar` rather than `Char`, since the latter is two bytes in Delphi.

```
PPAnsiChar = ^PAnsiChar;
PPPAnsiChar = ^PPAnsiChar;

procedure Method(Arg: PPPAnsiChar); cdecl;
```

or

```
procedure Method(var Arg: PPAnsiChar); cdecl;
```

If you want to index into the variable like an array, add `{$POINTERMATH ON}` before declaring the types

Comment: Your solution works. I've been struggling with this for the last hour.